# Saving Get-ADObject result to variable gets slow when using -Properties

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to run the following cmdlet and save its output into my $query variable.

```
$query = Get-ADObject -Server $ldapServer -Credential $account -LDAPFilter "(&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))" -SearchBase $ldapDN  -Properties "GivenName", "Mail"
```

The LDAP query runs pretty well, (about 10 seconds on a 6000+ LDAP database). The returned resultset contains about 150 user objects. The strange thing happens when trying to itterate over the $query variable like so:

```
$query
```

Or:

```
foreach($object in $query){$object}
```

**The iteration is incredibly slow (about 10-30 seconds per object)**

Everything works fine and fast when the query is not saved to a variable, like running the command:

```
Get-ADObject -Server $ldapServer -Credential $account -LDAPFilter "(&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))" -SearchBase $ldapDN  -Properties "GivenName", "Mail"
```

Also when using a formatting cmdlet like so:

```
$query = Get-ADObject -Server $ldapServer -Credential $account -LDAPFilter "(&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))" -SearchBase $ldapDN  -Properties "GivenName", "Mail" | ft
```

However, I need the 'objects' for itteration. So Saving the text output doesn't help me here. 
Even more confusing, is when itterated over once by just calling '$query', the following calls to the once printed objects are processed fast in all further calls. 
**Also, when the '-Properties' parameter is excluded from the 'Get-ADObject' cmdlet, the result saved to the $query varible is also processed quickly!** The  '-Properties' parameter appears to cause it to slow down, (so I guess it has nothing to do with memory limits, considering I have sufficient free memory).

Does anybody know:

1. Why this happens?
2. Why it happens only when using -properties?
3. How to solve the problem / some workaround (I can't use the 'DirectorySearcher' class, since it's not possible to specify a user to run the 'LDAP' query for that class, and calling 'runas' is not an option).

Comment: Have you tried using just get-aduser?

Comment: Do you need only givenname and mail ?

Comment: i need more, but to limit the risk that it may be a memory problem, i limited the properties to those two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with `select-object` that convert `$query` in a `pscustomobject`

```
$query = Get-ADObject -Server $ldapServer -Credential $account `
-LDAPFilter "(&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))"  -SearchBase $ldapDN `
 -Properties "GivenName", "Mail" | select givenname, mail
```

Comment: Works! However, i'm still curious why this bug happens.

Comment: Maybe the query return an object with many information. Usually I use the Quest cmdlet for this kind of job.

Comment: @masi Maybe a difference in round trips to the LDAP server? You could run NetMon (Network Monitor) to get LDAP packet traces to see if this is the case.

Comment: Nope, it's not the LDAP Server. It respons all 6000 entries in less then 20 seconds now. But still, when saving them into a variable in Powershell, iterateing over the variable is painly slow.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = Get-ADObject -Server $ldapServer -Credential $account `
-LDAPFilter "(&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))"  -SearchBase $ldapDN `
 -Properties "GivenName", "Mail" 
$query| Export-Clixml c:\temp\myquery.xml
```

After you exported the variable $query will be fast to enumerate/display.  I was planning to import it again... But then discovered the speed issue in the variable was gone.

However I like CB's answer better.